# Some deep links may be failing because your web domains aren't associated with your app notification in google play store

Tags: android

This means that on Android 12 and above, your app can't accept traffic from some web URLs. To fix issues and make sure that users go directly to your app, go to the Deep links page.

is it require to do something on this notification?

notification received but could not understood whats wrong in my app even i didnt integrated deep link functionality.

Comment: did you get some answers?